# google script conditional formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have put together a google spreadsheet that highlights the first four cells in a row if the value in cell 6 is within 3 days of the current date, but I cannot figure out how to add an if/and statement to exclude all entries that have "East" in row E.

This is the code that I have had success with, minus the exclusion of East not highlighting.

```
onEdit(e) {
if (e) { 
var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = e.source.getActiveRange(); 
if (r.getRow() != 2 && ss.getName() == "Sheet1") {
Days_Remaining = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),6).getValue();
rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,4);
if (Days_Remaining < 3.8) {
rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#FF0000");
} else if (Days_Remaining == 'N/A') {
rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#ffffff");
} else if (Days_Remaining > 3.9) { 
rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#ffffff");
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqtCuK7ex8ZNdGxKLUZpQnZ3UzRCV3VoclVDbFVqQnc#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new Google Sheets, you can simplify by using [Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/78413?hl=en)

If not, you need to get the values in column 5 as well and add an IF block based on that. For example:

```
Follow_up = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),5).getValue();
```

And then, before you check Days_Remaining, you should add

```
If(Follow_up <> "East") {//rest of the checks here }
```